# Can I improve this controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is this action ok? Can it be improved in any way? Should I extract the setting up of the order to a private method and just call that? Or is it fine and in line with the 'Rails way'?

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @product = Product.find(session[:product])
  @order.amount = session[:total_amount]
  @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  @order.product_id = @product.id
  @order.product_price = @product.price
  @order.voucher = @voucher_value
  @order.friend_id = session[:friend_id]
  if @order.save
    if @order.purchase
      render :action => "success"
      reset_friend_session_codes
    else
      render :action => "failure"
    end
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

TIA.

Comment: You may also want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and see what response you get there.

Comment: Thanks! Posted it there too, should I delete this one now?

Comment: If people start voting it down maybe but given that someone posted an answer it seems okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would factor out as much as I could into a private method in the order model and call it with one of the model hooks, such as `before_validation`. That's too much logic for an action, and tramples all over MVC.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How would I get session info and other variables into the hook method? (Without having to use virtual attributes, as that'll mean it will end up pretty much the same as I have above?)

Comment: It won't make sense to set virtual attributes, but any of those lines that can be done without session data should be moved to the model.